# Copy to Clipboard is not working

Tags: javascript, zeroclipboard

I am trying to use Zeroclipboard for copying and i have multiple targets to copy
The code i am using is

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//css.freekishopping.in/freekishopping/wp-content/themes/freekishopping/assets/js/ZeroClipboard.js"></script>
<style>.clip_button{background:#063;padding:4px;width:100px;}</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
////copy to clip
    var clip = null;

   function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id); }

   function init() 
   {
      clip = new ZeroClipboard.Client();
      clip.setHandCursor( true );
   }

   function move_swf(ee)
   {    

      copything = document.getElementById(ee.id+"_code").value;
      clip.setText(copything);

         if (clip.div)
         {    
            clip.receiveEvent('mouseout', null);
            clip.reposition(ee.id);
         }
         else{ clip.glue(ee.id);   }

         clip.receiveEvent('mouseover', null);
var url=document.getElementbyId(ee.id+"_url").value;
    window.open(url,"_BLANK");
document.getElementbyId(ee.id).innerHTML=copything;

   }    

</script>
</head>
<input type="hidden" id="123_url" value="http://google.com">
<input type="hidden" id="123_code" value="ABCD">
<div id='123' onMouseOver='move_swf(this)' class='clip_button'>COPY</div>
```

The tutorial for this code is working fine but my modify code is not working. 
i just did a little modification for opening alink after clicking on the button and then displaying the coupon code in the button
This code is hosted here freekishopping(dot)in/test.html
Can any 1 check where i am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I've opened your page and this is the error from error console

```
TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'clip.setText')               test.html:20
```

so i opened the page and it seems that your clip field is not initialised yet. you should try to call your init() function first.

---

the part of your code that goes like this

```
function move_swf(ee)
{
  copything = document.getElementById(ee.id+"_code").value;
  clip.setText(copything);
```

try change it into like this.

```
function move_swf(ee)
{
  init();
  copything = document.getElementById(ee.id+"_code").value;
  clip.setText(copything);
```

Comment: not i am getting ` Cannot read property 'setText' of null` in console any idea how to solve this ?

Comment: well, technically the same. the error indicate that the object (which is `clip` in here) is haven't been initialised yet. and the error itself is different because you probably using different browser that i'm using (mine is safari). To solve this, the easiest way is, of course, call your `init()` function before you call the `setText` method.

Comment: i have already changed the position can you check the code and tell me what to do ?

Comment: the copy thing is working now but the url is not opening

Comment: your function call is wrong. it's `getElementById` not `getElementbyId`. and a little bit of advice, try to check the web console first dude. it's your buddy when you try to develop a website ;)

Comment: but i m facing another problem whenever i hover on that code its opening the url 
is there any way to open the url after the user click on code ?